# Minimum sdp for server-client architecture

Tags: webrtc, sdp

I'm working on a voice chat where the user is already logged in and the server is used as a mcu.

I would like to know what is the minimum sdp from the client and for the server to have a valid webrtc connection ?

Will this be ok ?

Client SDP for the create offer:

```
v=0
o=-[nat timespamp] [NUMBER] IN IP4 127.0.0.1
s=[room id]
m=audio 9 UDP
a=sendrecv
```

Server SDP for the answer:

```
v=0
o=-[nat timespamp] [NUMBER] IN IP4 [SERVER PUBLIC IP]
s=[room id]
m=audio 9 UDP
a=sendrecv
```

I know that this is much shorter than what create offer generates by default:

```
v=0
o=- 3642263768141042597 2 IN IP4 127.0.0.1
s=-
t=0 0
a=group:BUNDLE 0
a=msid-semantic: WMS
m=audio 9 UDP/TLS/RTP/SAVPF 111 103 104 9 0 8 110 112 113 126
c=IN IP4 0.0.0.0
a=rtcp:9 IN IP4 0.0.0.0
a=ice-ufrag:4Wbh
a=ice-pwd:c7Scj0h00zsv9rokqNlN86Aq
a=ice-options:trickle
a=fingerprint:sha-256 46:19:A7:0F:39:30:B6:D5:1E:DF:8F:32:9B:D0:D2:3A:5D:0F:C4:37:AD:75:7E:1A:12:82:7D:68:7B:0E:C1:B9
a=setup:actpass
a=mid:0
a=extmap:1 urn:ietf:params:rtp-hdrext:ssrc-audio-level
a=extmap:2 http://www.ietf.org/id/draft-holmer-rmcat-transport-wide-cc-extensions-01
a=extmap:3 urn:ietf:params:rtp-hdrext:sdes:mid
a=extmap:4 urn:ietf:params:rtp-hdrext:sdes:rtp-stream-id
a=extmap:5 urn:ietf:params:rtp-hdrext:sdes:repaired-rtp-stream-id
a=recvonly
a=rtcp-mux
a=rtpmap:111 opus/48000/2
a=rtcp-fb:111 transport-cc
a=fmtp:111 minptime=10;useinbandfec=1
a=rtpmap:103 ISAC/16000
a=rtpmap:104 ISAC/32000
a=rtpmap:9 G722/8000
a=rtpmap:0 PCMU/8000
a=rtpmap:8 PCMA/8000
a=rtpmap:110 telephone-event/48000
a=rtpmap:112 telephone-event/32000
a=rtpmap:113 telephone-event/16000
a=rtpmap:126 telephone-event/8000
```

But are all these parameters mandatory to make it work ?

If not what would be the minimum SDPs ?

Answer (score 0):

https://webrtchacks.com/update-anatomy-webrtc-sdp-anton-roman/ describes the elements of the SDP and https://webrtchacks.com/the-minimum-viable-sdp/ discusses how to minimize things. You might want to read both.

Your SDP has the wrong profile ("UDP") is not defined, is lacking a dtls fingerprint, ice-ufrag, ice-pwd, a codec definition (rtp) and an ice candidate at least.

Comment: How do I get the ice things ? Normally I get them with a stun server, but I read for a client-server communication I don't need a stun server

Comment: You'll need to implement ICE in your server. See https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc8445, in particular the section about lite implementations.